# Jenkins fails "shell exec" task for paths with quotes

Tags: jenkins, continuous-integration, shell-exec, xcopy

I have windows based Jenkins host and local folder like this:

```
"c:\Archive\JenkinsBuilds"
```

When I'm using shell exec to copy build to that folder (all the content of Release folder) I'm getting an error. The issue is because Jenkins adds single quotes automatically and shell exec expectes double quotes only:

I defined env variables:

```
FINAL_PACKAGE = My-Project\bin\Release
BUILDS_DEST = c:\Archive\JenkinsBuilds\My-Project\$BUILD_NUMBER
```

and shell exec:

```
xcopy /i /f /v $FINAL_PACKAGE $BUILDS_DEST
```

And during execution I see in logs:

```
xcopy /i /f /v 'My-Project\bin\Release' 'c:\Archive\JenkinsBuilds\My-Project\17'
```

How to force Jenkins to use double quotes.
If I specify them manually Jenkins adds single quotes in any case what generates the same error:

```
"Invalid number of parameters"
```

Comment: are you sure the problem is with quotes? and not that your trying to use shell on windows?

Comment: I didn't get the comment and but yes, I'm sure because when I'm opening the shell (on windows) and execute it... it doesn't work with single quotes and works well with double quotes.

Comment: You should be using "Execute windows batch command" if you're on windows... https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/XShell+Plugin

Comment: I was not aware about this plugin. Thanks.. unfortunately it doesn't resolve my variables: c:\Jenkins\workspace\My-Project>xcopy /i /f /v $FINAL_PACKAGE $BUILDS_DEST 
File not found - $FINAL_PACKAGE

Comment: yea, of course, it is windows shell now: xcopy /i /f /v "%FINAL_PACKAGE%" "%BUILDS_DEST%"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @Cole9350 for advise.
On windows it is better to use [windows batch command](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/XShell+Plugin)

And variables usage will be different:

```
xcopy /i /f /v "%FINAL_PACKAGE%" "%BUILDS_DEST%"
```